# Mongo and Node.js: unable to look up document by _id

Tags: node-mongodb-native

I'm using the Express framework and Mongodb for my application.

When I insert objects into the database, I use a custom ObjectID. It's generated using mongo's objectid function, but toString()ed (for reasons i *think* are irrelevant, so i won't go into them). Inserts look like this:

```
collection.insert({ _id: oid, ... })
```

The data is in mongo - i can db.collection.find().pretty() from mongo's cli and see it exactly as it's supposed to be. But when I run `db.collection.find({_id: oid})` from my application, I get nothing ([] to be exact). Even when I manually hardcode the objectID that I'm looking for (that I **know** is in the database) into my query, I still can't get an actual result.

As an experiment, I tried `collection.find({title: "test title"})` from the app, and got exactly the result I wanted. The database connection is fine, the data structure is fine, the data itself is fine - the problem is clearly with the _id field.

Query code:

```
var sid = req.param("sid");
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get("stories");
collection.find({'_id': sid }, function(err, document) {
  console.log(document.title);
});
```

Any ideas on how I can get my document by searching _id?

**update:** per JohnnyHK's answer, I am now using findOne() as in the example below. However, it now returns null (instead of the [] that i *was* getting). I'll update if I find a solution on my own.

```
collection.findOne({'_id': sid }, function(err, document) {
  console.log(document);
});
```

Comment: Could you please add what you get when you run ```db.collection.find({_id: oid})``` plus the value of oid (string or ObjectId...)?

Comment: I'd do the find "test title" and stare at the result with a debugger or lots of print statements to see what the _id field really is.

Answer (score 1):

`find` provides a cursor as the second parameter to its callback (`document` in your example). To find a single doc, use `findOne` instead:

```
collection.findOne({'_id': sid }, function(err, document) {
  console.log(document.title);
});
```

Comment: this alone does not work. now, instead of getting [], i get null (i just double checked to make sure the document existed - it does). but using findOne is a good point, and i'll move forward looking towards a solution that implements this.

Comment: @dylan Then your `_id` query value (`sid`) doesn't exactly match any document.  This assumes your `_id` is a string as you describe in your question, but if it's actually an ObjectID then you need to convert `sid` to an ObjectID by calling `mongodb.ObjectID(sid)`.

Comment: right - i've looked into and tried variations of that. still returning null. i'll go through my application and check what all has happened to the sid as it's been passed around for good measure.